# admin access for user profile

Tags: user-profile, administration

I have an admin in India and I need to give him access so he can run a script to create user's mysite. I gave him farm admin access and looks like i can't add AD group to mysite web application user permission. it only takes individual account. What are the steps or where all i need to grant him access so he can run the script without access denied. I already added him to content databases (not all sharepoint database). i ran a script to give him allow ps script access on databases. he is already in the admin group of all the sp servers.

```
$dbs = Get-SPDatabase
$adgroup = "sgi\SG-india-SharePointAdmins"
foreach($d in $dbs) {Add-SPShellAdmin $adgroup -database $d}

Get-SPWebApplication | foreach { 
 $webApp = $_
 $webApp.ContentDatabases.Name
 $webApp.ContentDatabases | Add-SPShellAdmin $adgroup

 $webApp | foreach-object {$_.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity($adgroup)}

 }
```

Comment: Do you gave him access to run PS Scripts in SharePoint Configuration Database?

Comment: does get-spdatabase list config db as well. just check it does